# Using a Loading Indicator for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget-package

I'm relatively new to WPF and I would like to add a loading indicator. I found https://github.com/100GPing100/LoadingIndicators.WPF which has some nice pre-made loading indicators and I installed the NuGet Package for it but I'm having a hard time implementing them to my window.

So I added

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:loadin="clr-namespace:LoadingIndicators.WPF;assembly=LoadingIndicators.WPF"
    ...
>

Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LoadingIndicators.WPF;component/Styles/LoadingDoubleBounce.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

But when I try to add one of the loading indicators to my grid I get an error on the dynamic resource

```
<Grid x:Name="TagLoadingIndicator" Panel.ZIndex="1">
    <loadin:LoadingIndicator SpeedRatio="{Binding SpeedRatio}" IsActive="{Binding IsDoubleBounceActive}" Style="{DynamicResource LoadingIndicatorDoubleBounceStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

The error I get is

> The resource "LoadingIndicatorDoubleBounceStyle" could not be
>   resolved.

From what I saw in other websites, I am adding it to the ResourceDictionary correctly... And I'm assuming that by installing the NuGet package, I have the resource already defined. I can still run the application but the indicator is missing. What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That key exists in the `Styles.xaml` file. So add a reference to it in your resources.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LoadingIndicators.WPF;component/Styles/LoadingDoubleBounce.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LoadingIndicators.WPF;component/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that as on of the references in the demo code. It's working now.